# Two different implementations of the same template constructor using SFINAE

Tags: c++11, constructor, overloading, sfinae

Is it possible to have two different constructors that get enabled through SFINAE depending on the traits? I have tried the following, but didn't succeed.

```
template<typename... Args>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename F,
    typename FunTrait = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<F, std::function<void(Args...)>>::value>::type>
    Foo(F&& func)
    {
       //Do one thing
    }


    template<typename F,
    typename FunTrait = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<F, std::function<void(Args...)>>::value>::type>
    Foo(F&& func)
    {
       //Do another thing
    }
};

Foo<int> someFoo([](){});
```

This is telling me that the constructor is already defined on the second constructor, but they cannot both be enabled for a single type of F.

Comment: Sorry missed a line

Comment: So what exactly isn't working?

Comment: A [mcve] is more helpful than just a class (with missing semicolon).  If you get compiler or linker errors, please post all the errors.  If you compile but get unexpected behavior, please show the actual output and explain what you expected to see instead.